# init and sessionAuthenticated in ApplicationRouteMixin can not be together

Tags: authentication, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I lost my head for this problem: `init` and `sessionAuthenticated` in `ApplicationRouteMixin` can not be together!

In my **routes/application.js** I have something like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';
import other from '../other';

export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {

init: function () {
    otherJsImImportingMainFunction();
},

sessionAuthenticated() {
    this.transitionTo('someRoute');
    debugger;
}

actions: {
    ...
}

};
```

In this situation my code doesn't work.

I authenticate and then sessionAuthenticated() is never called.

If I comment out "init:" it works good.

How to fix this?

I'm doing well importing this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NOTE: If you do override init for a framework class like Ember.View, be sure to call this._super(...arguments) in your init declaration! If you don't, Ember may not have an opportunity to do important setup work, and you'll see strange behavior in your application.

[Ember docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_init)